# Factoshiny error in tag: argument is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I take the liberty of asking you because I have been using data analysis packages : factoshiny, factomineR. I recently noticed the update which goes further than the previous ones. In particular, the factoshiny interface which gives the idea of ​​a fully integrated tool.

However, I get an error message when I leave the PCA section to go to the HCPC:
1-Under shiny interface I have the following message: "ERROR: argument is missing, with no default"
2-Under Rstudio :

1/ with my data (655 individuals et 11 variables) :

```
Warning in HCPC(resultsHCPCshiny, kk = 100, nb.clust = -1, graph = FALSE) :
  No consolidation has been done after the hierarchical clustering since kk is different from Inf (see help for more details)

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6505
Warning: Error in tag: argument is missing, with no default
  69: tag
  68: tags$div
  67: div
  66: conditionalPanel
```

2/   with data decathlon :

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6505
Warning: Error in tag: argument is missing, with no default
  70: tag
  69: tags$div
  68: div
  67: conditionalPanel
```

Here is the line of code for the decathlon data :

```
data("decathlon")
res <- Factoshiny(decathlon)
```

Here is the information issues from the code sessionInfo()
Voici les informations issues du code sessionInfo() :

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] questionr_0.7.0      Factoshiny_2.2       FactoInvestigate_1.6 shiny_1.3.2         
[5] FactoMineR_2.3       factoextra_1.0.6     ggplot2_3.2.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ggrepel_0.8.1        Rcpp_1.0.1           mvtnorm_1.0-11       lattice_0.20-38     
 [5] tidyr_0.8.3          assertthat_0.2.1     digest_0.6.20        foreach_1.4.4       
 [9] mime_0.7             R6_2.4.0             backports_1.1.4      stats4_3.6.3        
[13] pcaPP_1.9-73         evaluate_0.14        highr_0.8            colourpicker_1.0    
[17] pillar_1.4.2         rlang_0.4.0          lazyeval_0.2.2       rstudioapi_0.10     
[21] miniUI_0.1.1.1       DT_0.7               rmarkdown_1.14       labeling_0.3        
[25] htmlwidgets_1.3      munsell_0.5.0        broom_0.5.5          compiler_3.6.3      
[29] httpuv_1.5.1         xfun_0.8             pkgconfig_2.0.2      htmltools_0.3.6     
[33] tcltk_3.6.3          flashClust_1.01-2    tidyselect_0.2.5     tibble_2.1.3        
[37] codetools_0.2-16     rrcov_1.4-7          crayon_1.3.4         dplyr_0.8.3         
[41] withr_2.1.2          later_0.8.0          MASS_7.3-51.5        leaps_3.0           
[45] grid_3.6.3           jsonlite_1.6         nlme_3.1-144         xtable_1.8-4        
[49] gtable_0.3.0         magrittr_1.5         scales_1.0.0         shinyjqui_0.3.3     
[53] promises_1.0.1       scatterplot3d_0.3-41 doParallel_1.0.15    mice_3.8.0          
[57] robustbase_0.93-5    generics_0.0.2       iterators_1.0.10     tools_3.6.3         
[61] glue_1.3.1           DEoptimR_1.0-8       purrr_0.3.2          crosstalk_1.0.0     
[65] yaml_2.2.0           parallel_3.6.3       missMDA_1.16         colorspace_1.4-1    
[69] cluster_2.1.0        shinydashboard_0.7.1 knitr_1.23
```

Do you have an idea of ​​the problem ?

Have you noticed this problem ? 
Thanks
bye

Comment: It's good I found.
You had to update the shiny, ggplot2 and htmlwidgets packages. Thanks
How can we close the question?

Comment: you can add a reply below, might be useful for someone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good I found. You had to update the shiny, ggplot2 and htmlwidgets packages. Thanks How can we close the question?